# Any workaround for JSONPATH wildcard not supported in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("""select get_json_object('{"k":{"value":"abc"}}', '$.*.value') as j""").show()
```

This results in null while it should return 'abc'. It works if I replace `*` with `k`.

I'm aware of limited JSONPath support (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object)

but is there a way to achieve this is Spark SQL.

Comment: is that your JIRA? ;) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37857

Also, the Hive doc you referenced is not relevant to Spark.

Comment: I actually found another JIRA which was apparently similar to my issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Spark JIRA "[Any depth search not working in get_json_object ($..foo)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37857)" open for full JsonPath support.

Until it is resolved, I'm afraid creating a UDF that uses a "general-purpose" JsonPath implementation might be the one and only option:

```
> spark-shell --jars "json-path-2.7.0.jar"                      
:
scala> import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

scala> val r = JsonPath.read[net.minidev.json.JSONArray]("""
     | {"k":{"value":"abc"},
     |  "m":{"value":"def"}}
     | ""","$.*.value")
r: net.minidev.json.JSONArray = ["abc","def"]

scala>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate ! Will have to make a UDF for now

Answer (score 0):

It is a late answer but might be useful for future visitors. For a moment of writing Spark still has limited support of JsonPath, meaning that we still need a workaround. I am using pyspark, but the solution should work everywhere.

`get_json_object` in spark cannot unravel key values by wildcard but we can try and leverage `from_json` function in a way of creating a MAP of string and other maps or arrays `fn.explode(fn.from_json('value', 'MAP<STRING,MAP<STRING, STRING>>'))`.

Together with explode you can unpack the map into a separate column of keys and a column of values. Here is a snippet for testing:

```
spark.sql("""
select explode(from_json('{"k": {"value":"abc"}}', 'MAP<STRING,MAP<STRING, STRING>>'))
""").show()

Output:
+---+--------------+
|key|         value|
+---+--------------+
|  k|{value -> abc}|
+---+--------------+
```